# Where can I find/download LWUIT Themes

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I saw a really awesome LWUIT theme today and graphics is not really my thing. Does anyone know anywhere I can download (or even purchase) good LWUIT themes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the LWUIT trunk from Subversion, you can find some projects, examples with themes. Take a look at them. http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show

Comment: I have checked all of them. They all use the default theme provided by LWUIT

Comment: I see that the Tipster,Timezone themes are not the default theme.

Comment: In the Lwuit Resource Editor you have more defaults themes

Comment: Tipster and Timezone themes are included as default themes in Resource Editor. That's what I meant by default theme provided by LWUIT.

Comment: codenameone? Not really suitable for the functionality I want. LWUIT is just cool. I have seen a tutorial on youtube for developing your own theme using Photoshop, but that's the thing. I'm not a designer and this will take me some considerable time probably to yield a poor result.

Comment: So, I think It will be hard to you to find lwuit themes to download.

Comment: Seems this is the best answer I can get, and I actually discovered a different theme called oceanFish theme in the svn. Thanks.